# how to show alert popup after finishing database processing?

Tags: c#

is there any way to show label that shows "uploading.." while my button click is processing?

I am doing it in this way

`

protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{

        lblOutput.Text="uploading..";


    HttpPostedFile postedFile = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
    string ClientFileName, ServerFileName;

    if ((FileUpload1.HasFile && FileUpload1.PostedFile != null) || txtUrl.Text!="")
    {
       try
       {
            HttpPostedFile myFile = FileUpload1.PostedFile;

            if (fileType == "Image")
            {
                if (fileExt == ".jpg" || fileExt == ".gif" || fileExt == ".png" || fileExt == ".bmp" || fileExt == ".tif")
                {





                    ServerFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(ServerSavePathI, ClientFileName);

                    string serverPath = Server.MapPath(ServerFileName);

                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(serverPath);


                    dbInsert(fileType, fileName, fileExt, filePath+fileType+"/"+fileName.Replace(" ",string.Empty)+fileExt, url);



                }
```

}

}

`

but it showed after my file has been uploaded already.

Am i doing something wrong? or is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Where is the *database processing* done?

Comment: Do you use standard asp.net FileUpload control or something else for uploading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code at the end of btnUpload_Click method: `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "FileUploadMessage", "jAlert('success', 'Your file has been uploaded.', 'Success Dialog');", true);`